# How can I loop through a (specific) list of worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2013 & I'm putting together a macro to automate copy/pasting the actuals data in a number of sheets (one sheet per site, ~80 odd sites, the workbook also has a number of other sheets that I don't want to touch) from E6:E157 to a column further to the right (which column depends on which month the data is for). I've got the code for the copy/paste bit (below) but I can't seem to get it to iterate through the sheets.

```
Dim month As Integer

month = Sheets("Group Incl Others").Range("b2")
    Sheets("Group Incl Others").Select
    Range("e6:e157").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, (13 + month)).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
```

What I would like to do is to provide the macro with the list of sheets to work through (either in a hidden sheet or in the code itself) & it step through the list doing the copy & paste. It's a (fairly) static list of sheets & would only change when we acquire new sites. Apart from the first sheet I want to process (Group Incl Others), the sheets are in contiguous group.

I've tried several suggestions from here & other sites, but it never goes to the next sheet. I've not used VBA for a very long time so I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a list of worksheets to be edited on some worksheet (doesn't matter which; hidden or not) and then select the worksheet names (not the column label if you put a title at the top of the list) and type *sheets2Bedited* in the name box to the left of hte formula bar. This will create a named range called *sheets2Bedited* which will be used in the following macro.

```
Dim mnth As Long, rWS As Range, ws0 As Worksheet
mnth= Sheets("Group Incl Others").Range("b2").Value
For Each rWS In Range("sheets2Bedited")
    With Sheets(rWS.Value)
        'either like this
        .Range("e6:e157").Offset(0, 13 + mnth) = _
          Sheets("Group Incl Others").Range("e6:e157").Value
        'or like this
        '.Range("e6:e157").Offset(0, 13 + mnth) = _
          .Range("e6:e157").Value
    End With
Next rWS
```

I could not read from your code what you actually wanted to use as a source and target on the *Copy, Paste Special, Values* operation so I offered two choices.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a spin. The source is the range e6:e157 in each sheet & the target is 14-25 columns to the right (April is month 1 in our accounting year & is therefore 14 columns to the right, May is month 2 & 15 columns to the right, etc) so it'll probably be the second option. The "Group incl others" sheet just happens to be the first sheet that needs to be edited.

Comment: @PaulJ - You're correct. It should have been the second option. If the *mnth* in B2 would change for each worksheet then that should be moved inside the `With ... End With` and changed to `mnth = .Range("b2").Value`.

Comment: It's coming up with "subscript out of range" on the With Sheets(rWS.Value) bit.

Comment: Perhaps your named range was not created correctly. Have a look at this sample workbook I quickly worked up [sheets2Bedited.xlsb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/sheets2Bedited.xlsb)

Comment: The named range looks ok (in both the name manager & when I select it from the drop down box to the left of the formula box) & it's not comming up with the out of range error any more, but it's not changing sheets...

Comment: Sub Macro1()
    Dim mnth As Long, rWS As Range
    mnth = Sheets("Group Incl Others").Range("b2")
    For Each rWS In Range("SheetsforMacro")
        With Sheets(rWS.Value)
            Range("e6:e157").Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, (13 + mnth)).Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,   Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        End With
    Next rWS
    End Sub

Comment: The above is what I've got for the macro at the moment (not sure how to get it formatting correctly in a comment)

Comment: The macro framework I wrote for you does not reply on `.Select`, `.Selection`, `ActiveCell` or `ActiveSheet`. Additionally, it transfers values directly, not with `.Copy` then `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`. If you want to take a step backwards and use those methods, then you should be able to figure them out.